# Overriding CakePHP conventions. One table with 2 columns of the same model

Tags: cakephp, model, conventions

Suppose I have a table/model Products.
Suppose I have a table/model Equivalencies which has among its columns this 2:

- original_id
- equivalent_id

Both original_id and equivalent_id have as foreign keys the primary key of Products. So, I can't follow the convention of naming original_id as product_id, because I also have to deal with equivalent_id (which would also be product_id).

What should I do?

Currently, I have the Product model configured as this:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Original' => array(
        'className' => 'Equivalency',
        'foreignKey' => 'original_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => '',
        'table' => 'products',
    ),
    'Equivalent' => array(
        'className' => 'Equivalency',
        'foreignKey' => 'equivalent_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
);
```

Could anyone tell me if this is how it's supposed to be done?

**What I Want**
I want to be able to find all the equivalencies of a  given product, but with conditions over the relation (the one with original_id, equivalent_id).
This doesn't work:

```
$original = $this->Product->find('all',
        array(
            'contain' => 'Product.Original.deleted_equivalent = false',
            'conditions' => array('Product.id' => $id)
        ));
```

Comment: You're not being overly clear what you want to do... If you mean link the model to the equivalencies model as two different instances then what you've done looks fine (albeit excessive) - it is totally feasible to for example to an SQL join on the same table more than once with different aliases (which is what you're doing here)

Comment: Let me edit my post and explain further.

Comment: @scrowler, I just posted what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: try `'contain' => array('Original.deleted_equivalent' => false),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is fine, that's the way you should do it.

Your call to find is not.

Try this

```
$original = $this->Product->find('all',
    array(
        'contain' => array('Equivalent'),
        'conditions' => array('Product.id' => $id)
    ));
```